# How to do the aggregation count on the group by with C# Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

My requirement is to do aggregation count on columns when do GroupBy JobID.
I want to aggregation count on the columns - Sent, Delivered, Read and Failed and also want to check those columns has existed or not.
If Sent and Delivered columns has existed and it has value, I need to count on them.
At my collection, there are two records that Sent and Delivered column has existed and has value.
Other Read and Failed are not existed totally.
So the output will be “SentCount” : “2”,
“DeliveredCount” :“2”,
“ReadCount” : 0,
“FailedCount” : 0

Please help me the way to write the query in C# and I am new to mongodb.

Thank you so much in advance.

My collection is the below.

```
[{

"JobID": "Jobid1",
"TemplateName": "templateName",
"CampaignName": "campaignName",
"Channel": "channel",
"SentBy": "sentBy",
"SentFrom": "sentFrom",
"Sent": "2022-08-01",
"Delivered": "2022-08-01"

}, {

"JobID": "Jobid1",
"TemplateName": "templateName",
"CampaignName": "campaignName",
"Channel": "channel",
"SentBy": "sentBy",
"SentFrom": "sentFrom",
"Sent": "2022-08-01",
"Delivered": "2022-08-01"

}, {

"JobID": "Jobid1",
"TemplateName": "templateName",
"CampaignName": "campaignName",
"Channel": "channel",
"SentBy": "sentBy",
"SentFrom": "sentFrom"

}]
```

I want to ouput like below

```
{
  "JobID" : "Jobid1",
  "TemplateName" : "templateName",
  "CampaignName" : "campaignName",
  "Channel" : "channel",
  "SentBy" : "sentBy",
  "SentFrom" : "sentFrom",
  "SentCount" : "2",
  "DeliveredCount" :"2",
  "ReadCount" : 0,
  "FailedCount" : 0    
}
```

Best Regards,
Kyi Moh

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a conditional sum, e.g. in plain MQL:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$JobID",
      SentCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: "$Sent",
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      DeliveredCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: "$Delivered",
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      ReadCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: "$Read",
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      FailedCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: "$Failed",
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This creates the following output on your data:

```
[
  {
    "DeliveredCount": 2,
    "FailedCount": 0,
    "ReadCount": 0,
    "SentCount": 2,
    "_id": "Jobid1"
  }
]
```

See this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4CsDGOmuHwj) to test.

In C#, you can create the output like this:

```
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<Item>()
    .AppendStage(new BsonDocument("$group",
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", "$JobID" },
                { "SentCount",
                    new BsonDocument("$sum",
                    new BsonDocument("$cond",
                    new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "if", "$Sent" },
                                        { "then", 1 },
                                        { "else", 0 }
                                    })) },
                { "DeliveredCount",
                    new BsonDocument("$sum",
                    new BsonDocument("$cond",
                    new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "if", "$Delivered" },
                                        { "then", 1 },
                                        { "else", 0 }
                                    })) },
                { "ReadCount",
                    new BsonDocument("$sum",
                    new BsonDocument("$cond",
                    new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "if", "$Read" },
                                        { "then", 1 },
                                        { "else", 0 }
                                    })) },
                { "FailedCount",
                    new BsonDocument("$sum",
                    new BsonDocument("$cond",
                    new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "if", "$Failed" },
                                        { "then", 1 },
                                        { "else", 0 }
                                    })) }
            }), BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance)
    .As<Item, BsonDocument, ItemSummary>();
var result = await coll.Aggregate(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```

I've defined the document classes like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [BsonElement("JobID")]
    public string JobId { get; set; }

    public string Sent { get; set; }

    public string Delivered { get; set; }

    public string Read { get; set; }

    public string Failed { get; set; }
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ItemSummary
{
    [BsonId]
    public string JobId { get; set; }

    public int SentCount { get; set; }
           
    public int DeliveredCount { get; set; }
           
    public int ReadCount { get; set; }
           
    public int FailedCount { get; set; }
}
```